# Handling swipe-to-delete of Firebase data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function to handle deleting rows of a table view that holds comments:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        selectedPost.comments.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        selectedPost.commentAuthors.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        // Remove from Firebase
        let postsCommentsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("postComments").child(self.postID)
        postsCommentsRef.observe(.childRemoved, with: { snapshot in

            // ??

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
}
```

With this, the comment is deleted from the table view but since it's still in my database, it re-appears when the table is loaded again. I am trying to figure out how to delete the selected row/comment from the database at the same time as it is removed from the table.

I'm guessing I'll have to use `.childRemoved`, as seen above, but I'm not sure how to specify the exact comment to be deleted in the database. I understand deleting from the tableview, because I'm just removing the comment at the indexPath where it's located in the arrays `selectedPost.comment` and `selectedPost.commentAuthors` in my Post object. But they're not held in arrays in Firebase. This is how the comments are added:

```
// Upload to Firebase
func addComment(comment: String) {
    let postsCommentsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("postComments").child(self.postID)
    var commentData:  [String: String] = [:]
    commentData["userId"] = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.displayName!
    commentData["comment"] = comment
    postsCommentsRef.childByAutoId().setValue(commentData)
}

// Listens for changes, appends arrays & uploads table view
func observePostComments() {
    let postsCommentsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("postComments").child(self.postID)
    postsCommentsRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        let comment = snapshot.value as! [String: String]
        self.selectedPost.commentAuthors.append(comment["userId"]!)
        self.selectedPost.comments.append(comment["comment"]!)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Still getting used to Firebase so any help is appreciated!

EDIT (new):

New tableview method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let comment = selectedPost.comments[indexPath.row]
        selectedPost.comments.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        selectedPost.commentAuthors.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        // Remove from Firebase
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("postComments").child(self.postID).child(comment.key).removeValue()
    }
}
```

Observe post comments:

```
func observePostComments() {
    let postsCommentsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("postComments").child(self.postID)
    postsCommentsRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        let comment = snapshot.value as! [String: String]
        comment.key = snapshot.key
        self.selectedPost.commentAuthors.append(comment["userId"]!)
        self.selectedPost.comments.append(comment["comment"]!)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Observer function for removed comments:

```
func observePostCommentDeletion() {
    let postsCommentsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("postComments").child(self.postID)
    postsCommentsRef.observe(.childRemoved, with: { snapshot in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I am understanding this right.
Code you are using to remove comment isn't right.

```
// Remove from Firebase
        let postsCommentsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("postComments").child(self.postID)
        postsCommentsRef.observe(.childRemoved, with: { snapshot in

            // ??

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
```

What you are doing here is creating an observer, which listens for remove event and triggers when something gets removed from reference you set. This is actually not removing anything from firebase.
Your idea is right, but if you ask me this code should be located somewhere outside this block. Instead, you should put this code in block, to actually remove comment from database:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("postComments").child(self.postID).removeValue()
```

Put observer somewhere in `viewDidLoad` or create function for it like you did for `observePostComments()`. When it triggers, you should call `self.tableView.reloadData()` like you already wrote.

Comment: Thanks, I made an attempt at making an observer function to listen for deleted comments - I edited my post to show what I thought was right. Let me know if this is what you meant - this will just delete the selected comment, and not all of the comments, right?

Comment: I tried running the code above and it deletes all the comments on that photo, not just the one that's swiped.

Comment: @KingTim you have to create reference to the comment you want to delete.
This is the code you need. Just replace "commentKEY" with right comment key.
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("postComments").child(self.postID).child("commentKEY").removeValue()

Comment: I used `childByAutoId` in my `addComment` function so I'm not sure what the key would be. Sorry I'm kind of new to Firebase and getting a bit lost

Comment: @KingTim In observePostComments add line below let comment ... :
comment.key = snapshot.key

This way you read comment key from firebase and add it to comment dictionary.
Now, in code where you delete, get comment from array:
let comment = selectedPost.comments[indexPath.row]
Add this right before selectedPost.comments.remove(at: indexPath.row)
Now you can get comment key using comment.key and you can insert it in remove reference:
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("postComments").chi‌​ld(self.postID).chil‌​d(comment.key).remo‌​veValue()

Comment: Thanks that make some sense! I tried this (see my updated code edit) but I'm getting an error on the line `comment.key = snapshot.key`, saying 'Value of type [String : String] has no member key'.

Comment: @KingTim ok looks like we are on the right way. What kind of object is selectedPost? Can you copy some more code so I can see?

Comment: `selectedPost` is my Post object which holds everything in the post (image, likes, comment arrays, etc), plus the index path of the currently selected image. So I have a feed of posted images, then when one of the images is tapped you're taken to the screen we're on now which displays the bigger image and the tableview of comments, and selectedPost is set with `photoDetailController.selectedPost = posts[indexPath.row]`

Comment: @KingTim So you have custom class named Post for posts. If so, add property "key" to Post class.

class Post {
  var key:String = ""
.
.
.
}

Comment: Ok I added it but `comment.key = snapshot.key` still gets the same error. Should it be something like `self.selectedPost.key = snapshot.key`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138561/discussion-between-zassx-and-kingtim).